# No implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer when passing url in a form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, railstutorial.org

I'm trying to convert my form from

`<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>`

to

`<%= form_for(@user, url: signup_path) do |f| %>`

However, since the form is a shared form for both create and update actions, I am trying to use

`<%= form_for(@user, yield(:url)) do |f| %>` in the form and

`<% provide(:url, "signup_path") %>` in the view.

But I am getting the error that

```
ActionView::Template::Error:ActionView::Template::Error: 
no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer
```

Anyone with an idea what causes that error?

Comment: Try assigning a variable called URL to be what you want the path to be, and then use that variable for URL

Comment: <%= form_for(@user, url: url) do |f| %>

Comment: Hi @Mark that's what I am trying to do with the yield. I cannot put the url directly because in the create action, the url is `signup_path`, while in the update action, the url is `edit_user_path`. Thats why I am putting a place holder and trying to use he `provide` to provide the url

Comment: Just found that the answer is to have 
`<%= form_for(@user, url: yield(:url)) do |f| %>` 
and then provide the url as 
`<% provide(:url, signup_path) %>`